# The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed. What is the cause of this?

Tags: android, markup

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">
 <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send" />
</LinearLayout>

<resources>
<string name="app_name">becreativebuddy</string>
</resources>
```

im getting the error in line 18 out of 20. I am following a tutorial word for word because i am very new to this. I would like to get into the habit of localizing, but is frustrating because when i dont have the  it compiles and runs just fine. I apologize if it is a simple error, but i have not found anything online the helps me. As mentioned before i am new to this so try to keep it simple.

Comment: you have added string resource in layout file

Comment: I bet "word for word" didn't say to put a resources tag in a layout.  That's your problem.  Read it again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete the 3 lines at the end of your file starting with `<resources>`. Move these 3 lines into a new file in your resources directory.