# The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ide

Im getting this error in my activity_main.xml on line 9 by  I have no idea why please help.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Is that the entire contents of your `activity_main.xml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would have googled this error, there are lots of post for the same. 
Eg:

[Android app, The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7090577/android-app-the-markup-in-the-document-following-the-root-element-must-be-well)

[The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed. What is the cause of this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16637251/the-markup-in-the-document-following-the-root-element-must-be-well-formed-what)

[Error : The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed Please help I am new at android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16620042/error-the-markup-in-the-document-following-the-root-element-must-be-well-forme)

and so on. 
Basically it says that you can only have **one root element for the whole XML** file. The xml sniplet you've shown does not look complete. Just make sure that you only have one root element for the XML file and rest of them are child of that root element. Hope this helps. If it doesn't then please do post the complete XML file for us to help better.

**Update**

In the code shown above you have two `FrameLayout` root elements. There should be only one. So change it(based on your needs) to something like below, so that only one root element is there:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fullscreen_custom_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FF000000">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Perfect thank you. I thought the other answer helped me but after saving it gave the same error. But this did it.

Comment: Glad it helped. Just manage your XML according to your needs. keep in ind to just have one root element.

Answer (score 3):

Try `ctrl + shift + F` to your xml code which will format the code and try again after cleaning the project.it will work.